# why does my timer not work? even though timeRemaining is supposed to update, when i log it it remains at 5

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i tried the code i attached, and for some reason when i log it the state remains at 5.
i got it working by adding a counter ref but im sure its supposed to work even without it.
pleasse help.

```
import React , {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import styles from "./QuizTimer.module.css";

export default function QuizTimer(props)
{
  const timer = useRef();
  const [timeRemaining,setTimeRemaining] = useState(5);

  const handleTimeRemaining = () => {
    console.log(timeRemaining);
    if(timeRemaining ===1)
    {
      setTimeRemaining(5);
    }
    else{
      setTimeRemaining((prev) => {return prev-1;});
    }

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    timer.current = setInterval(handleTimeRemaining,1000);
  },[]);


  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1 >{timeRemaining}</h1>
        <p>seconds</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```js
const [time, setTime] = useState(5)

useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        setTime((prev) => prev === 1 ? 5 : prev - 1)
        console.log(time)
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(timer)
}, [time])
```

But remember, that you will get a previous value of timer, so you need to log it like this

```js
console.log(time === 1 ? 5 : time - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is not precise, consider using the Date object instead see this example:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function App() {
  const now = new Date();
  const countBackFrom = 5;
  
  const [date, setDate] = useState(now);
  const [expirationDate, setExpirationDate] = useState(new Date(now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + countBackFrom)));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setDate(new Date());
    }, 1000)

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [])

  useEffect(()=> {
      if (date >= expirationDate) {
        const now = new Date();

        setExpirationDate(
          new Date(new Date(now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + countBackFrom)))
        );
      }
  }, [date, expirationDate]);

  return (
    <p className='clock'>
      {date.toLocaleTimeString()}
      {expirationDate.toLocaleTimeString()}
    </p>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The handleTimeRemaining function was defined when timeRemaining = 5, and it will always remain at timeRemaining = 5 during execution.
That is the reason.
[image]